# Xui.js page anatomy

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, xui

**Info:**
I am using JQuery Mobile (in Phonegap) for building pages and navigating via them by $.mobile.changePage() or hash.

**This is JQuery Mobile page anatomy:**

```
<div id="foo" data-role="page"> 
    <div  data-role="header">...</div> 
    <div  data-role="content">...</div> 
    <div  data-role="footer">...</div> 
</div>
```

**Problem:**
I am looking for *XUI.js* page anatomy, because there is really poor documentation about this library.

Comment: I think XUI.js is more for DOM, From the site: http://xuijs.com/ "it does not try and dictate a page structure or widget paradigm" more docs are here: http://xuijs.com/docs/basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Phill said, XUI isn't designed for managing DIVs as "pages", but it can be done. Andrew Lunny has built a lightweight page control in his starter application. You can inspect the source on [Github](https://github.com/alunny/phonegap-start) and see how he converts the DIVs to pages. It requires a combination of CSS and setting classes on the DIVs in question.

Again; jQueryMobile is designed very specifically to do this all for you. XUI is not.

Comment: I wasn't sure if xui is able to do it similarly to jquery mobile. But example which you posted is very helpful. Thank you both for solution.